# RavenDB PatchRequest PatchCommndType.Inc

Tags: ravendb

I can't find a documentation for handling "PatchRequest not found".

I have a user with age attribute, i've succeeded to increase his age with PatchCommndType.Inc,

But, i don't know how to handle a case where the user is not store in Raven and then i would like to store that user to Raven.

I've choose to use patch request, due to time saving.

what is the best practice for that??

for example:

i have the user:

Name:john, Age:20

if the user is stored in Raven i'd like to increase his age with PatchCommndType.Inc
else, i'd like to store him to Raven

Answer (score 0):

You can't, patch is assumed to always work.
If the doc doesn't exists, we just don't execute it.